# Does Mathematica have a built-in date picker?

Tags: dynamic, interface, interactive, date-and-time

Does *Mathematica* have an interactive date input control that lets the user choose a date by browsing to a calendar view and returning the selected date as a date list? For example, something like the [Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) in jQuery.

Comment: No, it doesn't. But it shouldn't be difficult to build one using the basic controls that are available.

Comment: Maybe a starting point [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8135982/656841).

Comment: There is also some Wolfram examples with date pickers but looks like @rm -rf has delivered :)

Comment: I don't know if it is smart about about picking dates, but there is [this](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/StableMarriages/) for finding stable marriages. (Or did you mean to pick dates from trees? That part was ambiguous...)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

#### Date-picker implementation in *Mathematica*

The following is my implementation of a simple date-picker. The current date is highlighted in `LightBlue` and the weekends are highlighted in `LightGreen`. The selected date is always highlighted in `LightRed` (the default selection is the current date).

You can tap into this calendar by using the `Dynamic` values for `year`, `month` and `date` for your custom function (a simple example in the last `Panel`).

[image]

#### Code:

Note that the following implementation uses `DayName`, which was introduced in version 9. You might have to roll your own if you want to use this in earlier versions of *Mathematica*.

```
With[{startDayOffset = Thread[{Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, 
        Friday, Saturday} -> Range@7]},   
    DynamicModule[{month, year, date, today = DateList[][[;;3]], daysInMonth, calendarView},
        
        {year, month, date} = today;

        daysInMonth[m_Integer,y_Integer] := DatePlus[{y, m, 1}, {{1, "Month"}, {-1, "Day"}}][[3]];

        calendarView[m_Integer, y_Integer] := Grid[
            {Style[#, FontWeight -> Bold]& /@ {"Su","M","Tu","W","Th","F","Sa"}} ~Join~ 
            Partition[Range@daysInMonth[m, y], 7, 7, {DayName[{y, m, 1}] /. startDayOffset, 1}, {""}],
            Frame -> All,
            FrameStyle -> LightGray
        ] /. { i_Integer :> Button[
                    i, 
                    date=i, 
                    Appearance->"Palette", 
                    Background -> Which[
                        date==i, LightRed,
                        {year, month, i} === today, LightBlue,
                        !FreeQ[DayName[{year, month, i}],Saturday|Sunday],LightGreen,
                        True,White
                    ],
                    ImageSize->{32,32}
                ],
                s_String :> Button[
                    s, 
                     , 
                    Appearance -> "Palette", 
                    Enabled -> False, 
                    Background -> If[!s == "", LightGray],
                    ImageSize->{32,32}
                ]
            };

        Panel[
            Column[{
                Row[{
                    Style["Year ",FontSize->16], PopupMenu[Dynamic@year, 1970 ~Range~ 2020],Spacer[10]
                    Style["Month ",FontSize->16],PopupMenu[Dynamic@month, Range@12 ]
                }],
                Dynamic@calendarView[month, year],
                Panel[Dynamic@StringForm["Selected date: `1`/`2`/`3`", date, month, year]]
            }]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: +1 That's a really nice bit of Mathematica code. And, unlike the Mayan calendar, it doesn't stop in a couple of days.

Comment: No month rules, leap year stuff and data necessary if you just use `DatePlus[date, {{1, "Month"}, {-1, "Day"}}][[3]]`, with `date` the first of the month you're interested in.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Thanks, that's much better :) Updated

Answer (score 25):

There is a built-in `DateSetter`:

```
{Developer`DateSetter[Dynamic@date], Dynamic@date}
```

[image: ScreenGIF]

By default the first selectable date is tomorrow and one can only go to future months. However, the option `` NotebookTools`DateSetterRange `` can be used to set the first selectable date to sometime in the past,

```
{Developer`DateSetter[Dynamic@date, NotebookTools`DateSetterRange -> {2015, 1, 1}], 
 Dynamic@date}
```

[image: DateSetterInAction1]

or to only allow a certain date range.

```
{Developer`DateSetter[Dynamic@date, 
  NotebookTools`DateSetterRange -> {{2015, 1, 1}, {2015, 5, 2}}], 
 Dynamic@date}
```

[image: DateSetterInAction2]

Comment: +1. Do you know which versions have this function?

Comment: @MichaelE2 No, I don't know. I'm only aware that version 9.0.1 already has it, but without proper functioning.

Comment: Note [this comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16542/does-mathematica-have-a-built-in-date-picker/16550#comment50737_17166) by JxB. Apparently their answer was inspired by this but it supposedly crashes the frontend.

Comment: This has no way to visit past months, but for me it's reliable so long as I only need the present or future.

Comment: @MichaelStern By default the first selectable date is tomorrow and one can only go to future months. However, there is the option ``NotebookTools`DateSetterRange``. I'll add two examples how it can be applied to my answer.

Comment: It doesn't work with a custom setter like Developer`DateSetter[Dynamic[date,(date=#)&]] so it's not fully working yet.

Answer (score 12):

Here is one that should work in version 6 and later. The full code is at bottom.

Here is what it looks like:

```
{dateSetter[Dynamic[d]],Dynamic[d]}
```

[image: dateSetter button]

I did not incorporate the year here, but you could put it in a Tooltip or add it to the button's graphic.

And when you click on the button you get

[image]

Incorporate this into a `Manipulate` using `{d,dateSetter[#]&}` as a control:

```
Manipulate[DynamicModule[{difference},
 difference=DateDifference[DateList[][[1;;3]],d];Style[Row[{DateString[d,{"DayShort"," ","MonthName"," ","Year"}]," ",difference/.{x_/;x<-1:>Row[{"was ",-x," days ago."}],
 x_/;x==-1->"was yesterday.",
 x_/;x==0->"is today.",
 x_/;x==1->"is tomorrow.",
 x_:>Row[{"is ",x," days from now."}]}}],"Text"]],{{d,DateList[][[1;;3]],""},dateSetter[#]&}]
```

[image: dateSetter in Manipulate]

The code:

```
Clear[monthDays];
monthDays[year_,month_]:=DateDifference[DateList@{year,month},DateList@{year,month+1}];
monthDays[date_List/;Length@date<=6]:=monthDays[date[[1]],date[[2]]];
monthDays[date_String]:=monthDays@@DateList[date][[1;;2]];

Clear[monthDates];
monthDates[year_,month_]:=DatePlus[DateList@{year,month,0},#]&/@Range[monthDays[year,month]];
monthDates[date_List/;Length@date<=6]:=monthDates[date[[1]],date[[2]]];
monthDates[date_String]:=monthDates@@DateList[date][[1;;2]];

Clear[dayNames];
dayNames[]=DateString[{0,0,#},"DayNameShort"]&/@Range[-1,5];

Clear[dayOfWeek];
dayOfWeek[date_List]:=DateString[date,{"DayNameShort"}]/.Thread[dayNames[]->Range[0,6]];
dayOfWeek[year_,month_]:=dayOfWeek[{year,month,1}];

Clear[previousMonth];
previousMonth[year_,month_]:=Take[monthDates[year,month][[All,3]],-dayOfWeek[year,month]];

Clear[nextMonth];
nextMonth[year_,month_]:=Take[monthDates[year,month+1][[All,3]],7-dayOfWeek[year,month+1]];

Clear[monthArray];
monthArray[year_,month_]:=Module[{array},array=Partition[Join[Button[Style[#,Gray,Bold,FontFamily->"Helvetica"],Appearance->None,ImageSize->All,Enabled->False]&/@previousMonth[year,month],Button[Style[#,Darker[Cyan,.4],Bold,FontFamily->"Helvetica"],DialogReturn[{year,month,#}],Appearance->None,ImageSize->All]&/@monthDates[year,month][[All,3]],Button[Style[#,Gray,Bold,FontFamily->"Helvetica"],Appearance->None,ImageSize->All,Enabled->False]&/@nextMonth[year,month]],7,7,1,{}];
If[Length@array<6,Append[array,ConstantArray[Button[Style["",Gray,Bold,FontFamily->"Helvetica"],Appearance->None,ImageSize->All,Enabled->False],7]],array]]

Clear[dateSetter];
dateSetter[Dynamic[date_]]:=DynamicModule[{tmpdate,mousepos,storeddate},
   If[Length@date<3,date=storeddate=tmpdate=DateList[][[1;;3]],tmpdate=storeddate=date];
   Button[Dynamic[Graphics[{Lighter[Red,.3],Rectangle[{0,.6},{1,1},RoundingRadius->.1],
            White,Rectangle[{0,0},{1,.5},RoundingRadius->.1],
            Rectangle[{0,.3},{1,0.7}],
            EdgeForm[GrayLevel[0.4]],FaceForm[],Rectangle[{0,0},{1,1},RoundingRadius->.1],
            White,Text[Style[DateString[storeddate,{"MonthNameShort"}],Bold,FontFamily->"Helvetica"],{0.5,0.85}],
            GrayLevel[0.3],Text[Style[DateString[storeddate,{"DayShort"}],Bold,FontFamily->"Helvetica",FontSize->Scaled[.5]],{0.5,0.35}]},
            ImageSize->40]],
          mousepos=MousePosition["ScreenAbsolute"];
          tmpdate=DialogInput[Dynamic@Style[Grid[Join[{{Row[{Button[Style["\[LeftPointer]\[LeftPointer]",Medium,Bold,FontFamily->"Helvetica"],tmpdate=DatePlus[tmpdate,{-1,"Year"}],ImageSize->All,Appearance->None],
                     Button[Style["\[LeftPointer]",Medium,Bold,FontFamily->"Helvetica"],tmpdate=DatePlus[tmpdate,{-1,"Month"}],ImageSize->All,Appearance->None]},Spacer[3]],
                     Style[DateString[tmpdate,{"MonthName"," ","Year"}],Bold,FontFamily->"Helvetica",Medium],
                     SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,SpanFromLeft,
                     Row[{Button[Style["\[RightPointer]",Medium,Bold,FontFamily->"Helvetica"],tmpdate=DatePlus[tmpdate,{1,"Month"}],ImageSize->All,Appearance->None],
                     Button[Style["\[RightPointer]\[RightPointer]",Medium,Bold,FontFamily->"Helvetica"],tmpdate=DatePlus[tmpdate,{1,"Year"}],ImageSize->All,Appearance->None]},Spacer[3]]}},
                     {Style[#,FontFamily->"Helvetica",Medium]&/@dayNames[]},
                     monthArray[tmpdate[[1]],tmpdate[[2]]]],Background->{{None},{GrayLevel[0.8]}},Frame->True,Spacings->{.5,.5}],Small,FontFamily->"Helvetica"],
                  WindowMargins->{{mousepos[[1]],Automatic},{Automatic,mousepos[[2]]}},WindowElements->None,WindowFloating->True];
          If[tmpdate=!=$Failed,date=storeddate=tmpdate,tmpdate=date],Method->"Queued",
      Appearance->None]
]
```

Comment: The appearance and functionality is inspired by ``Developer`DateSetter[]``, pointed out to me by @WReach. That function is not documented, and it crashes my front end session quite reliably.

Comment: I think that you forgot to include the `monthDates` definition.

Comment: @GustavoDelfino It's there right after the `Clear[monthDates]`.

Comment: Thank you @JxB. I fell victim to the invisible scroll bars in Mac OS X.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a silly one that works only in version 9:

```
DynamicModule[{x = 0}, AngularGauge[Dynamic[x], {0, 365}, 
  GaugeFrameStyle -> Black, 
  GaugeFrameSize -> .01,
  ScaleDivisions -> 0,
  GaugeFaceStyle -> Directive[LightGreen, EdgeForm[]], 
  GaugeFaceElementFunction -> "PlateauSector",
  GaugeLabels -> 
   Dynamic[
    Style[
     DateString[
      DatePlus[{2013, 1, 1}, x], {"DayName",   " ", "MonthName", " ", 
       "Day" , ", ", "Year"}], 10 , Bold, Gray]]]]
```

[image: silly gauge]