# How to keep Mouseover visible while control has focus/cursor?

Tags: programming, dynamic, gui-construction, inputfield, user-interface

I have a `DateObject` and `InputField` that I am using to collect an inputted date.  `Mouseover` works well to switch between the two items.  However, if the cursor is in the `InputField` and the mouse drifts out of it then it switches back to the `DateObject`.

```
reportDate = Today;
Mouseover[
 Dynamic[With[{date = Interpreter["Date"][reportDateInput]}, 
   If[DateObjectQ@date, reportDate = date, reportDate]], 
  TrackedSymbols :> {reportDateInput}]
 ,
 InputField[
  Dynamic[reportDateInput,
   {
    None,
    With[{date = Interpreter["Date"][#]}, 
      If[DateObjectQ@date, reportDateInput = #, 
       reportDateInput = "Try again. Date not recognised."]] &
    }],
  String,
  FieldHint -> "Enter the report date."
  ]
 ]
```

How do I keep the `InputField` visible as long as it has focus (e.g. text cursor in it)?  Should I be using some other combination of controls?  I'm only interested in the `reportDate` variable. The other is just a means to that end. Also, I would like not to have to use `Interpreter` twice.

This combination is to easily get a date from as there is no built in date picker at the moment. I know there are some custom date pickers out there (e.g. [16542](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16542)) but I'd rather use this simpler method of free-text input at the moment. Also, I'd like to know how to do this for other UI elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function: "EventHandler", just like follows:

```
reportDate = Today;
a = Dynamic[
   With[{date = Interpreter["Date"][reportDateInput]}, 
    If[DateObjectQ@date, reportDate = date, reportDate]], 
   TrackedSymbols :> {reportDateInput}];
b = InputField[
   Dynamic[reportDateInput, {None, 
     With[{date = Interpreter["Date"][#]}, 
       If[DateObjectQ@date, reportDateInput = #, 
        reportDateInput = "Try again. Date not recognised."]] &}], 
   String, FieldHint -> "Enter the report date."];
Dynamic[EventHandler[a, {"MouseMoved" :> (a = b)}]]
```

---

How about this

```
reportDate = Today;
c = a = Dynamic[
    With[{date = Interpreter["Date"][reportDateInput]}, 
     If[DateObjectQ@date, reportDate = date, reportDate]], 
    TrackedSymbols :> {reportDateInput}];
b = InputField[
   Dynamic[reportDateInput, {None, 
     With[{date = Interpreter["Date"][#]}, 
       If[DateObjectQ@date, reportDateInput = #; c = a, 
        reportDateInput = "Try again. Date not recognised."]] &}], 
   String, FieldHint -> "Enter the report date."];
Dynamic[EventHandler[Dynamic[c], {"MouseMoved" :> (c = b)}]]
```

Comment: Thanks for trying but this does not appear to update `reportDate` and it does not return to the formatted output of `reportDate` after update.

Comment: The update works well. I did not consider `EventHandler` as I had only seen it in passing.