# How to make a set of interdependent popup menus work?

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

Here is my code that is not working.

```
vars = <|"x" -> <|"Q" -> "Quant", "bins" -> {10, 20, 30, 40}|>,
"y" -> <|"Q" -> "Qual", "bins" -> {"Male", "Female"}|>|>;

doVarSpecs[vars_] := DialogInput[
DynamicModule[{varlist, var, oplistquant, oplist, op, vallist, val},
g[var_] := Block[{},
 oplist = 
  If[vars[var, "Q"] === "Quant", Keys@oplistquant, 
   Take[Keys@oplistquant, 2]];
 op = First@oplist;
 Print[op, oplist];
 vallist = vars[var, "bins"]; val = First@vallist;
 ];
varlist = Keys@vars; var = First@varlist;
 oplistquant = {"=" -> SameQ, "\[NotEqual]" -> UnsameQ, 
 "\[LessEqual]" -> LessEqual, "\[GreaterEqual]" -> GreaterEqual};
 g[var]; Print[varlist]; Print[oplist]; Print[vallist];
 Column[{
  Style["Choose a Set of Variable Relations", 22, Darker@Blue],
  "  ",
  Row[{
   "Variable: ",
   PopupMenu[Dynamic[var, (var = #; g[var]) &], varlist], "  ",
   Dynamic[PopupMenu[Dynamic[op], oplist], 
    TrackedSymbols :> {oplist}], "  ",
   Dynamic[PopupMenu[Dynamic[val], vallist], 
    TrackedSymbols :> {oplist}]
   }],
  "  ",
  Row[{Button["OK", DialogReturn[{var, op, val}]], CancelButton[]}]
 }
 ]
], WindowTitle -> "Variable Specification Selector"]
```

For a simpler case, the question was answered previously,

[My previous similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98885/how-to-make-the-choice-list-for-one-popupmenu-depend-on-the-choice-in-another)

In this case, when var is changed, g[var] is called and both oplist and vallist are updated, but the PopupMenu controls that use them are not updated.

The assistance of the Stack Exchange community would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found a mechanism that works for my needs in this case.  The key seems to be embedding pure functions (making all of the symbols visible to Dynamic).  A code fragment follows:

```
doVarSpecs[vars_] := DialogInput[
 DynamicModule[{varlist, var, oplist, oplist1, oplist2, op, val},
 varlist = Keys@vars; var = First@varlist;
 oplist = <|"=" -> SameQ, "\[NotEqual]" -> UnsameQ, 
  "\[LessEqual]" -> LessEqual, "\[GreaterEqual]" -> GreaterEqual|>;
 oplist1 = Keys@oplist; oplist2 = Take[oplist1, 2];
 q = vars[var, "Q"] === "Quant";
 Column[{
  Style["Choose a Set of Variable Relations", 22, Darker@Blue],
  "  ",
  Dynamic@Row[{
    "Variable: ",
    PopupMenu[
     Dynamic[var, (var = #; q = (vars[var, "Q"] === "Quant"); 
        op = First@oplist1; val = First@vars[var, "bins"]) &], 
     varlist, MenuStyle -> 18],
     "  ",
    PaneSelector[{
      True -> PopupMenu[Dynamic[op], oplist1, MenuStyle -> 20],
      False -> PopupMenu[Dynamic[op], oplist2, MenuStyle -> 20]
      }, q], "  ",
    Dynamic@
     PopupMenu[Dynamic[val], vars[var, "bins"], MenuStyle -> 18]
    }],
   "  ",
   Row[{Button[" OK ", DialogReturn[expr], BaseStyle -> 18], "  ",
    Button[" Cancel ", DialogReturn[{}], BaseStyle -> 18]}]
   }, BaseStyle -> 18]
  ], WindowTitle -> "Variable Specification Selector" ]
```

Example call

```
vars = <|"Age" -> <|"Q" -> "Quant", 
    "bins" -> {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80}|>,
 "Gender" -> <|"Q" -> "Qual", "bins" -> {"Male", "Female"}|>,
 "Race" -> <|"Q" -> "Qual", 
    "bins" -> {"White", "Black", "Hispanic", "Asian", "Other"}|> |>

doVarSpecs[vars]
```