# How to plot events in a weekly/daily view?

Tags: visualization

Are there any functions or resources to plot events in a calendar view like this?

[image]

I'd like to use this with the [google service](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/service/GoogleCalendar.html):

```
cal = ServiceConnect["GoogleCalendar"]
cal["EventDataset"]
```

For testing purposes here is code to generate the events:

```
nEvents = 25;
events = Thread[{Partition[Sort[ResourceFunction["RandomDate"][
    {Now, Now + Quantity[5, "Days"]}, nEvents*2]], 2], 
   Table[ResourceFunction["LatinizedText"][RandomInteger[{1, 20}]], nEvents]
}]
```

Criteria for an acceptable answer includes:

- Looks like the above calendar from twitch
- Shows event details like title and time length info
- Handles overlapping events like a normal calendar view
- Shows different calendars (sets of events) in different colors

**Related:**

- [Calendar view outline](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61094/calendar-view-outline)
- [Does Mathematica have a built-in date picker?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16542/does-mathematica-have-a-built-in-date-picker)

Comment: Any data to work with? Any criteria to identify the answer?

Comment: @Kuba Thanks, I added data to work with if you're uncomfortable publishing your personal gcal :) Also the criteria for an answer.

Comment: It is rather that I am lazy but that is fine with the book. The question should come with data to play with to avoid misinterpretation. Thanks.